# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at HTMLElement.demoRespondToClick

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

My game works but there is a problem when I try to restart the game. It is showing error in innerHTML.

In this case, I created two decks and so comparing cards from two decks cause an error in innerHTML. Previously, I compared cards from only 1 deck and it worked without error.

```
function demoRespondToClick(e) {
  //First deck
  let demoClickedCard = e.target;
  if (demoClickedCard.classList.contains("democard") &&
    !demoClickedCard.classList.contains("open", "show", "match")) {

    demoClickedCard.classList.add("open", "show");
    demoCheckCards.push(demoClickedCard);
  }

  // Second Deck
  let clickedCard = e.target;
  if (clickedCard.classList.contains("card") &&
    !clickedCard.classList.contains("open", "show", "match") &&
    demoCheckCards.length === 1) {

    clickedCard.classList.add("open", "show");
    checkCards.push(clickedCard);
  }

  // IF THE FIRST CARD(DEMO DECK) YOU SELECT MATCHES THE CARD ON THE SECOND DECK, YOU WIN

  //if (demoCheckCards.length === 1) {
    //demoCardboard.classList.add("stop-event");
//PREVIOUS CODE
   // if (checkCards.length === 1) {
    //  cardboard.classList.add("stop-event");
    //}
if (demoCheckCards.length === 1 && checkCards.length === 1) {
    demoCardboard.classList.add("stop-event");
    cardboard.classList.add("stop-event");

  // COMPARING CARD FROM FIRST AND SECOND DECK AND HERE IS THE ERROR
   if (checkCards[0].innerHTML === demoCheckCards[0].innerHTML)(Error line)  {
      matched();
      //AFTER YOU WIN, YOU ARE ALERTED
      alert("You won the challenge");
    } else {
      // IF CARD DOES NOT MATCH, YOU ARE ALERTED
      alert("You lose the challenge");
    }

  }
}

// IF CARDS MATCH, THEN THIS IS THE FUNCTION
function matched() {
  demoCheckCards[0].classList.add("match");
  checkCards[0].classList.add("match");
  demoMatchedCards.push(demoCheckCards[0]);
  matchedCards.push(checkCards[0]);
  checkCards = [];
  demoCheckCards = [];
  matchedCards = [];
  demoMatchedCards = [];
  cardboard.classList.remove("stop-event");
  demoCardboard.classList.remove("stop-event");
}

//RESTART FUNCTION
const restart = document.querySelector(".restart");
function restartGame() {
  checkCards = [];
  demoCheckCards = [];
  matchedCards = [];
  demoMatchedCards = [];
  cardboard.innerHTML = "";
  demoCardboard.innerHTML = "";

  createCardDeck();
  createDemoCardDeck();
}
restart.addEventListener("click", function(){
  restartGame();
});
```

I expected the output to restart my game properly without causing an error in innerHTML

ERROR MESSAGE:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined at HTMLElement.demoRespondToClick

Comment: `checkCards[0]` is `undefined`, hence `checkCards` is empty

Comment: It seems that on the first click you add an element to *demoCheckCards* but not to *checkCards*. You only test if `demoCheckCards.length === 1` before attempting to access `checkCards[0]`, which may not have been assigned a value yet (and hence is undefined). You also need to check if `checkCards.length === 1` (but I can't see why you're using an array at all if it will only have one element).

Comment: if (demoCheckCards.length === 1 && checkCards.length === 1) {
    demoCardboard.classList.add("stop-event");
    cardboard.classList.add("stop-event"); I did this and now it is error free. Yes, RobG, I know I don't need an array but I make sure it works first of all regardless of what approach I take.

Comment: But the restart function is not working because the cards don't open when I click on it after restarting the game. I have edited my code. Please suggest me.